# Python - read file binary strange behavior

Tags: python, file, binary, bmp

I'm having a hard time reading file as byte array using python. At first glance everything is ok, but in some places I see something like (notice strange \rf and \x8bf)

```
\xe3\xd6\xb3\x9f\x8bf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\rf,\r\xcd\xbc\xab\xdd\xce\xbf\xdf\xd0\xc1
```

I'm guessing that it happens because of row adjustment to number that is dividable by 4. What I would like is to have an array of bytes just as they are seen in hexedit.

This is the code that I use

```
f = open('myfile.bmp', 'rb')
data = bytearray(f.read())
f.close()

print(data)
```

This is the picture

[image]

BTW - I'm using linux hexedit as hex editor.

Comment: Have you considered using pil to read the image?  Does a bitmap image have a header? did you want the header?

Comment: Yes, the bitmap has a header, but that doesn't matter. What I want is to make some bytes black if they are below some value. I haven't searched through PIL yet.